# Pandas value_counts(normalize=True) gives 'IntegerArray' object has no attribute 'sum'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, na

Pandas `value_counts(normalize=True)` fails when an extension datatype is used. For example, when creating an `int8` Series containing `pd.NA` would typically use `Int8` extension datatype but an error occurs: `AttributeError: 'IntegerArray' object has no attribute 'sum'`. What's the workaround?

```
pd.Series([1,pd.NA],dtype='Int8').value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is believed to be a regression bug, see [GH33317](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33317). Good news is that this is fixed on pandas 1.1.

```
pd.__version__  
# '1.1.0.dev0+2004.g8d10bfb6f'

pd.Series([1, pd.NA], dtype='Int8').value_counts(normalize=True) 

1    1.0
dtype: float64
```

---

**More Examples**

```
s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, pd.NA], dtype='Int8')
```

```
s.value_counts()
 
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: Int64

s.value_counts(normalize=True)

1    0.500000
2    0.333333
3    0.166667
dtype: float64

s.value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)

1      0.428571
2      0.285714
NaN    0.142857
3      0.142857
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why is value_counts() returning a dtype of float64 instead of Int8 or Int64? What are the rules?

Comment: @BSalita Because normalize=True performs a normalization (i.e., scaling) on your data and the result is float values between [0, 1]. Check my edit with more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I accepted your answer. I'm afraid I asked the question before giving it some thought. Thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the following can be used to workaround the issue:

```
# 1) works if you're ok with dropping NA
pd.Series([1,pd.NA],dtype='Int8').dropna().astype(int).value_counts(normalize=True)

# 2) works if you're ok with switching to a non-extension datatype such as float
pd.Series([1,pd.NA],dtype='Int8').astype(float).value_counts(normalize=True)

# 3) The issue may be fixed in a future versions of pandas. Try using a pandas version >= 1.1
```